# Is this questions "off-topic" reason valid?

Tags: discussion

Browsing the questions, I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228543/how-do-i-disable-steam-authentication-validation-on-my-cs-1-6-server), which has been put on hold due to being off topic.

The automated reason behind it is that the question is about unreleased or illegal software.

My main question is if OP is actually asking about illegal software. While he is asking about getting around the steam validation of CS 1.6, the game was released prior to steam becoming big, and it is quite valid that a user would have a physical disc that does not include a steam key.

I understand these responses are automated, and do not always accurately cover the main reason, but I thought I would post here for confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter-Strike 1.5 had non-Steam versions, but Counter-Strike 1.6 is a Steam-only game.

Incidentally, you can register any Valve CD key with Steam.  This includes any Half-Life 1 based games like Counter-Strike 1.5 and earlier.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for clearing it up